# Get request does not get the latest data added using Post

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use the data that I just added using Post, I send a get request to get all the data in the table, but it does not get the last data added is there a specific logic I should follow to get the updated data ?

Here is my controller :

```
app.ajoutProjet= function () {
  // adding a new project (CreatProjet() is a service that uses Post to create a new project)
 Projet.createProjet(app.ajoutData);
  // getting all the projects
 Projet.getProjet().then(function(result){
  for(var i=0;i<result.data.projetsListe.length;i++){                      
      //Enters this condition if the name of the project is the one we just added
    if(result.data.projetsListe[i].NomProjet==app.ajoutData.NomProjet){
      app.ajoutData.projet_id=result.data.projetsListe[i].IdProjet;
      CP.createCP(app.ajoutData);
     }
   }
 }); app.successMsg = 'Project added...Redirection';
```

**EDIT :**

Here is the Project Service :

```
//create a project
     createProjet : function (ajoutData) {
     return $http.post('/api/projets',ajoutData);
     },

 //get all projects
     getProjet : function () {
     return $http.get('/api/projets');
     }
```

So the project is created, but the get request doesn't return it in the list of projects, any suggestions ?

**EDIT**

Here is my Post method details :

```
router.post('/projets',function(req , res){
projet.Projet.sync({force: false}).then(function () {
  // Table created
 return projet.Projet.create({
     IdProjet : req.body.IdProjet,
     NomProjet: req.body.NomProjet,
     ResponsableApitech: req.body.ResponsableApitech,
     ResponsableClient: req.body.ResponsableClient,
     client_id: req.body.client_id,
     estArchive: req.body.estArchive

});

  });
});
```

Comment: show the `Projet` service

Comment: Where are you storing your data and how are you storing? Is there any failure on server side on post?

Comment: @Sagar I am storing the data in a sqlServer database , there is no failure in Post method when I check my DataBase the new project is created

Comment: R u sure that both post and get requests are happening to your server and get request is getting latest data from server. I suspect some issue on server side

Comment: @Sagar you can check my Edit for more details on the post method

Answer (score 1):

This occurs when you call the get request before the post request finished (while it is still processing). you need to wait until the post request is finished and then call the get request. For that, you can use **promise chain** mechanism

```
Projet.createProjet(app.ajoutData).then(function(response){
  return Projet.getProjet();
})
.then(function(result){
  for(var i=0;i<result.data.projetsListe.length;i++){                      
      //Enters this condition if the name of the project is the one we just added
    if(result.data.projetsListe[i].NomProjet==app.ajoutData.NomProjet){
      app.ajoutData.projet_id=result.data.projetsListe[i].IdProjet;
      CP.createCP(app.ajoutData);
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: This is a logical answer, but surprisenly it's not working

Comment: No errors , but it doesn't excecute the  code after `.then(function(response))`

Comment: can you create a demo

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the post method , even though the project was created, but there was no error check, therefore any code inside the `Projet.createProjet(app.ajoutData).then(function(response){//code})` didn't work, here is the modification I made :

```
router.post('/projets',function(req , res){
projet.Projet.sync({force: false}).then(function () {
  // Table created
 return projet.Projet.create({
     IdProjet : req.body.IdProjet,
     NomProjet: req.body.NomProjet,
     ResponsableApitech: req.body.ResponsableApitech,
     ResponsableClient: req.body.ResponsableClient,
     client_id : req.body.client_id,
     estArchive:req.body.estArchive

}).then(function(projet)
{
  if(!projet){
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'projet non ajouté'});
         }
   else{
  res.json({ success: true, message: 'projet ajouté', projet: projet});
       }
});
  });
});
```